# React material-table install issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-table

I am trying to use material-table in my project. Once I tried to install it I am getting below error.

[image: I]

Could someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem when i try to install `material-table`.

it's related to the `git`.
first you must install git and after that go to

> Environment Variable >> system variables

double click on `path` and check if this path are exist. if not, add this path

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\

[image: environment variable]